# Position of nearest and farthest set bit, Count of set bits of an integer

Tags: python, c++

**Problem:** How to find the position of the nearest and farthest set bit and count of set bits of an integer?

**E.g:**

*n -* *integer*

**Input**:  `n = 10`

**Output**:  `1, 3, 2`  *(nearest, farthest, count) respectively*

I tried this python script, are there any more efficient(time and space) ways to solve?

```
n = int(input())
near = far = count = 0
pos = 0
while n:
    bit = n & 1
    if bit:
        count += 1
        if not near: 
            near = pos
        far = pos
    pos += 1
    n = n // 2
```

Suggestions are accepted in any language.

Comment: Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the
[intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).  
"Show me how to solve this coding problem?" is off-topic for Stack Overflow.
You have to make an honest attempt at the solution, and then ask a *specific* question about your implementation.
Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing tutorials and documentation.

Comment: @Prune I just asked how I can improve the code and not "Show me how to solve this coding problem?". My question is a programming problem. Also, this is just my first ever question on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Asking for generic improvements is a coding problem.  Improvement of working code belongs on Code Review, not here.  Again, please review the intro tour.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The number of bits set is fastest found using a built-in function or inline assembler if your CPU supports it: e.g. `__builting_popcount()` (GCC for x86 population count instruction).

Whether - in your question - you intended "set" to apply to MSB or LSB is unclear.  Trivially, bits are usually numbered from 0 as the LSB through `sizeof(Type)*8-1` for the MSB.  That makes the most significant bit in a 32 bit int bit "31", and the least significant always bit 0.

If you mean the most significant **set** bit: the fastest way to find it is similarly with a built-in, e.g. `__builtin_clz()` (GCC for x86 CLZ count-leading-zeros instruction): just subtract the result from the index of your most significant bit (i.e. likely 31).  Similarly, `__builtin_ctz` can count trailing zeros to tell you the index of the least significant set bit, if any.

---

Those builtins won't be available for python, but there are likely to be alternatives for at least some, e.g.

- [`int.bitcount()`](https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/stdtypes.html#int.bit_count) gives you a population count.
- [`int.bit_length()`](https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/stdtypes.html#int.bit_length) tells you the number of bits needed to represent a value, which will be one more than the 0-based position of the most significant set bit

Python answers will be different if you're interested in arbitrary length integers...